# angularjs clearing the cache from a particular request

Tags: angularjs, caching

All the http requests I'm making are cached by default. Now, how do I clear the cache of a particular request?

Here is a situation to explain better. I have a REST API that sends two different kinds of data based on the authentication. Whenever the User has authenticated I need to clear the old data and make new request with the authentication. My controller gets refreshed but the API call is not being made as the call is already cached. It returns the old data.

Comment: How are you setting your cache? By setting the `$http Cache` property to true?

Answer (score 0):

You can us a custom cache object using Angular's built-in [`$cacheFactory`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory)

E.g

```
// cache the HTTP response
$http.get('myurl',{
    cache: true
}

// this object can now be retrieved using $cacheFactory 
var httpCache = $cacheFactory('$http'); 

// to remove the value from the cache, get the default $http cache, call the remove function and pass in the url 
var httpCache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');  
httpCache.remove('myurl');
```

Answer (score 0):

Telling our $http requests to make requests through our own custom cache is simple. Instead of passing a boolean true with the request, we can pass the instance of the cache.

```
    var myCache = $cacheFactory.get('myCache');
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/api/users.json',
  cache: myCache
});
// Or, using the .get helper
$http.get('/api/users.json', {
  cache: myCache
});
```

Now, instead of using the default cache, $http will use our custom cache.